# proper container / data-structre in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

I am writing a test for an address form. Therefore I need valid data.

My first approach is a method that returns a `HashMap<String, String>` with this data. (i.e. `m.put("city, "New York")`).

I am not sure if this is a proper data-structure in my case. I need just a container that holds the data so the data can be returned within a method. The number and the names of attributes are fixed, so they won't change while running. So I don't really need the functionality of adding and removing elements to the map dynamically.

Because of that I consider implementing a class called `AddressData` or something like that. And by creating `AddressData`-Objects the needed data could be assigned to the class attributes. So I can either make them public or fetch them via a getter method.

What do you think? Other data-structures suggestions?

They way I implemented it so far:

```
 public HashMap getValidData(String country){
    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

    if(country.equals("USA")){
        data.put("firstname","John");
        data.put("lastname","Green");
        data.put("city","New York");
    }
    else if(country.equals("Germany")){
        //add valid german address data
    }

    return data;
}
```

Implementation draft with a class:

```
 class AddressData{
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String city;

    public AddressData(String country){
        if(country.equals("USA")){
            firstname="John";
            lastname="Green";
            city="New York";
        }
        else if(country.equals("Germany")){
            //add valid german address data
        }
    }

    public String getFirstname(){ return firstname; }
    // other getters
}
```

Comment: In hashmap every key must be unique.

Comment: That's correct. No problem in my case. The keys are AddressData categories, i.e. firstname, lastname, city, ... I won't need two cities in one set of data.

Comment: Kindly provide what have you done till now in code. So that we can modify that and explain you. There are so many ways to design which you won't  even understand.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You should provide more details as asked by @SkrewEverything

Comment: I added some code examples. Please ask for more details if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed list of attributes, you should create a class that represents your form like the AddressData you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code more flexible, you should not have `String country` in your `AddressData`, otherwise, you will end up with many `if-else conditions` to handle many countries, rather store the countrycode as a key and `AddressData` as value object in the `HashMap` as shown below:

**AddressData class:**

```
public class AddressData {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String city;

    public AddressData(String firstname, String lastname, String city){
            this.firstname=firstname;
            this.lastname=lastname;
            this.city=city;
    }

    public String getFirstname(){ return firstname; }
    // other getters
}
```

**Usage of AddressData:**

```
HashMap<String, AddressData> data = new HashMap<String, AddressData>();
AddressData addressData1 = new AddressData("John", "Green", "New York");
data.put("USA", addressData1);
//You can add other address data
```